# How can I get the contents of a followed link in WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize, download

This is my last question for this I hope. I am using $mech->follow_link to try to download a file. For some reason though the file saved is just the page I first pull up and not the link I want to follow. Is this the correct way I should download the file from the link? I do not want to use wget.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w
    use strict;
    use LWP;
    use WWW::Mechanize;
    my $now_string = localtime;
    my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
    my $filename = join(' ', split(/\W++/, $now_string, -1));
    $mech->credentials( '***********' , '************'); # if you do need to supply     server and realms use credentials like in [LWP doc][2]
$mech->get('http://datawww2.wxc.com/kml/echo/MESH_Max_180min/') or die "Error: failed to load the web page";
$mech->follow_link( url_regex => qr/MESH/i ) or die "Error: failed to download content";
$mech->save_content("$filename.kmz");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Steps to try

1. First print the contents from your `get`, to make sure you're reaching a valid HTML page
2. Make sure the link you're going to is the third link called "MESH" (case-sensitive?)
3. Print the contents from your second `get`
4. Print the filename to make sure it's wellformed
5. Check that the file was created successfully

### Additional

- You don't need the unless in either case - it's going to work, or it's going to die

---

### Example

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;

   sub main{
   
      my $url    =  qq(http://www.kmzlinks.com);
      my $dest   =  qq($ENV{HOME}/Desktop/destfile.kmz);
      
      my $mech   =  WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck => 1);
      
      # if needed, pass your credentials before this call
      $mech->get($url);
      die "Couldn't fetch page" unless $mech->success;
      
      # find all the links that have urls to kmz files
      my @links  =  $mech->find_all_links( url_regex => qr/(?:\.|%2E)kmz$/i );
      
      foreach my $link (@links){               # (loop example)

         # use absolute URL path of the link to download file to destination
         $mech->get($link->url_abs, ':content_file' => $dest);
     
         last;                                 # only need one (for testing)
      }     
   }
   
   main();
```

Comment: how do you print the contents? I was trying print $mech->content( format => 'text' ); but it does not seem to work

Comment: So I am getting a new file which seems more correct, but the file it is downloading will not open up in google earth like it should. The file is a .kmz file which is what I now have the file downloading as(which I have updated in my code) but when I try to open the file its says it cannot be opened.

Comment: you can use `print $mech->response()->content()`, `print $mech->content()`, or even `print %{$mech->get($url)}`.  The `format=>'text'` will strip the HTML, which if it's an XML document with just elements and attributes, it might strip everything.

Comment: the link it is following though is not a page. just a download link

Comment: I think the problem is that it seems like it is trying to save the download page and now the object it is referring to. I could be wrong but the files it is downloading are not working properly

Comment: try a manual download.  After `$mech->get('http://datawww2.wxc.com/kml/echo/MESH_Max_180min/');`, type `$mech->get($urlOfDynamicLink); print $mech->contents();`

Comment: I used this $mech->get('http://datawww2.wxc.com/kml/echo/MESH_Max_180min/MESH_Max_180min_20100707-130536.kmz'); and it still doesn't work still. Is this the way you meant it to be?

Comment: Okay it should be print $mech->content(); On that note it is a bunch of jarbled symbols and beeps a bunch than finishes. I figure its jarbled symbols because its a .kmz file which is kind of like an image file

Comment: I think its the type of file I am trying to download. Is that anyway just to get the file to download rather than copying and saving its contents?

Comment: $mech->get() downloads the file, then you want to save it somewhere.  A .kmz file is an encoded KML file.  You can use a ZIP 2.0 algorithm to deflate it - ie, open it up with Winzip after you've saved it.

Comment: you can also save the file in one step: `$mech->get( 'http://datawww2.wxc.com/kml/echo/MESH_Max_180min/MESH_Max_180min_20100707-130536.kmz', ':content_file' => '20100707_130536.kmz' );`

Comment: It wont let me open it in winzip.... not sure what the problem is. I need a site that everyone can see to test it on.

Comment: Its like the encoding is different that it should be.

Comment: I've modified the answer to give you a working example, that should work.

Comment: Wow that works! I changed it around a little bit so that it now only pulls one file. THANKS ALOT! I appreciate all your help

Comment: I'm not attesting to the security or how robust it is, it's just an example of how it should work, barebones.  Glad you got it working.

Comment: Security should not be a problem since I am just running it off of my computer desktop use task scheduler. It is not on the web in any way except the 2 seconds it runs to do its thing. Is there a possible security issue in that?

Comment: Whenever a transfer is involved, there is possible security threats.  There's an opening between client and host for various methods to push through, but that is a whole other topic.  For what you're doing, you should be fine, provided the content is from a trusted source.

Comment: Yeah it is. The site is really just a directory of files

Comment: I really do appreciate your help. i have learned a lot from just you. I changed the program around to be just for one file and made it so the name changes to the date/time. is it the url_abs that is making it worked compared to what i had?

Comment: It could be, I'm not sure what you had before and it's difficult to see what the page is doing when I can't access it.  If the URLs had relative paths, then possibly.  Also, I think `$mech` would be empty if you chose to store the HTML file with the first `->get()` using `:content_file=>`.  There's many reasons why it might not have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want the 3rd link called 'MESH'?

Comment: no I did not realize until I went back and looked that it was looking for that specific link. It still does not work correctly but its a start. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Change `if` to `unless`.

Comment: Change the other _if_ to _unless_.